# transform text file to data table using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have text data available in the following format:

```
title:- sell product A,

description:- good quality product, fast service,

title:- sell product B,

description:- long lasting and good quality,

title:- buy product C,

description:- latest, good price
```

My goal is to get the text values into a dataframe with title and description values in corresponding columns.For example:

| title | Description |
| --- | --- |
| sell product A | good quality product, fast service |
| sell product B | long lasting and good quality |
| buy product C | latest, good price |

Comment: What is the format of the text file?

Comment: if by format you mean extension its a .txt file

Comment: No, I mean is it like separated by commas or something.

Comment: yes title and description are separated by commas but I have description values with commas present in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit Ver 1: Read file and Split to two columns

I am assuming that the pattern of your txt file is

```
title:-followed by data
description:-followed by data
title:-immediately after description line
description:-immediately after title line
```

If the pattern is not `title:-` and `description:-` sequence one after the other, the below code will NOT work.

I also assume there is no line blank line separating the title and description lines. If there are blank lines, I need to exclude the blank lines first before we do the splitting into title and description.

Read the full file into a list, then separate the data into two lists, then strip the leading text and load into pandas. I have added comments to each line so you can see what's being done.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('abc.txt','r') as f:
    data = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
    #read all rows into a list while also striping \n
    
#[::2] selects alternate rows, starting from 0. [8:] excludes "title:-"
#adding rstrip(',') removes the trailing "," from the string
title = [d[8:].rstrip(',') for d in data[::2]]

#[1::2] selects alternate rows, starting from 1. [14:] excludes "description:-"
#adding rstrip(',') removes the trailing "," from the string
desc  = [d[14:].rstrip(',') for d in data[1::2]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':title,'Description':desc})

print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
            Title                         Description
0  sell product A  good quality product, fast service
1  sell product B       long lasting and good quality
2   buy product C                  latest, good price
```

For the above example, the source data in `abc.txt` file is as follows:

```
title:- sell product A,
description:- good quality product, fast service,
title:- sell product B,
description:- long lasting and good quality,
title:- buy product C,
description:- latest, good price
```

## Edit Ver 2: If title & description rows do not match

If you are unsure of the datafile and want to play it safe, you can create the dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':pd.Series(title),'Description':pd.Series(desc)})
```

Here's an example:

I modified the input file to be as follows:

```
title:- sell product A,
description:- good quality product, fast service,
title:- sell product B,
description:- long lasting and good quality,
title:- buy product C,
description:- latest, good price
title:- buy product D,
```

The output of this will be:

```
            Title                         Description
0  sell product A  good quality product, fast service
1  sell product B       long lasting and good quality
2   buy product C                  latest, good price
3   buy product D                                 NaN
```

In the above example, the pattern breaks for the last row. We don't have a matching description value for the title. This results in a `NaN` in the `Description` column.

## Edit Ver 3: Input file has blank line after each row

If your input file has a blank line in between Title and Description rows, then you can add this code immediately after reading the file.

```
with open('abc.txt','r') as f:
    #read all rows into a list while also striping \n
    data = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
    
    #removing the blank lines from data
    data = data[::2]
```

Input sample file:

```
title:- sell product A,

description:- good quality product, fast service,

title:- sell product B,

description:- long lasting and good quality,

title:- buy product C,

description:- latest, good price

title:- buy product D,
```

Output DataFrame:

```
            Title                         Description
0  sell product A  good quality product, fast service
1  sell product B       long lasting and good quality
2   buy product C                  latest, good price
3   buy product D                                 NaN
```

Comment: Is your source datafile similar to what I have in the example? If your datafile looks different, then the code has to be modified a bit.

Comment: The reason ValueError: arrays must all be same length occurs only when your title and description rows dont match. Do you have a matching title and description row. Also do you have an additional enter key on the last row? If your last row does not end with description row, then you will get an error

Comment: the source datafile is similar to what you have. I will check if my data has some changes in the title and description values. Thanks

Comment: I posted a few options for you. I recommend using pd.Series to create your df and then check what's wrong